# Pegar valores separados por espaços em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Quero pegar o valores, por exemplo, 79 201 304 e armazena em um vetor cada número em uma posição.

Exemplo :

```
int array[0] = 79;
int array[1] = 201;
int array[2] = 304;
```

---

```
public static int Descriptografa(string txt, int p, int q, int d, int e)
    {
        string[] aux;
        int[] descrypt ;

        int phi, n, res = 0,i;
        string resultado;

        n = p * q;
        phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
        d = ((phi * 2) + 1) / e; // d*e ≡ 1 mod (φ n)

        for (i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
        {
            aux = txt.Split(' ');
            descrypt[] = Array.ConvertAll(aux, str => int.Parse(str));

            BigInteger big = BigInteger.Pow(descrypt[i], d) % n;
            res = (int)big;
            resultado = char.ConvertFromUtf32(res);
            Console.Write(resultado);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade de criptografia RSA e esta dando problema na parte de descriptografar preciso pegar o que o usuario digitar que vai ser numeros separados por espaços e armazenar em vetor com para descriptografar cada numero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var input = "10 15 20";
string[] output = input.Split(' '); // o separador nesse caso é o espaço
```

Aí você obteve um vetor de strings. Se o que você quer são inteiros, converta os itens do array para inteiros. Certifique-se de que são mesmo inteiros, se não a conversão vai falhar, obviamente.

Um exemplo da conversão utilizando o [`Array.ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int[] outputInt = Array.ConvertAll(output, str => int.Parse(str));
```

Veja funcionando no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/ftzp56).

Existem diversas formas de fazer essa conversão de string para inteiro. Pode até transformar em uma [`List<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) e utilizar o [`Cast<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx). Ficaria assim:

```
IEnumerable<int> outputInt = output.ToList().Cast<int>();
```

Tem também a solução de uma linha só. É o mesmo do de cima.

```
Array.ConvertAll("10 15 20".Split(' '), str => int.Parse(str)); // com Array.ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>
"10 15 20".Split(' ').ToList().Cast<int>(); // e com Cast<TResult>
```

Assim pode prejudicar a leitura. Eu utilizaria como no primeiro exemplo. Coloquei só para mostrar que não precisa de várias linhas para obter o resultado.

Comment: eu fiz isso com o split mas aparece que "não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "string[]" em "string""

Comment: eu consegui ver como funciona pelo Ideone, ve o que fiz de errado na resposta abaixo

Comment: o input seria o txt pq ele que vai receber os numeros que o usuario vai digitar

Comment: consegui agora, eu coloquei onde ele faz a conversão para int um int[] e funcinou, obg